# Error trying to install react native, not building correctly when running pod install

Tags: ios, reactjs, macos, react-native

I am trying to learn react native, and I'm running into an issue when trying to to install dependencies. I have installed CocoaPods and followed all steps via the documentation. I am unsure why I am getting this error. When running `pod install` and `pod install --repo-update` I am getting the following output:

```
tyler@Tylers-MacBook-Pro ios % pod install --repo-update     
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.61.5)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.61.5)
Installing Folly (2018.10.22.00)
Installing RCTRequired (0.61.5)
Installing RCTTypeSafety (0.61.5)
Installing React (0.61.5)
Installing React-Core (0.61.5)
Installing React-CoreModules (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTActionSheet (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTAnimation (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTBlob (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTImage (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTLinking (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTNetwork (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTSettings (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTText (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTVibration (0.61.5)
Installing React-cxxreact (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsi (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsiexecutor (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsinspector (0.61.5)
Installing ReactCommon (0.61.5)
Installing Yoga (1.14.0)
Installing boost-for-react-native (1.63.0)
Installing glog (0.3.5)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h

/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot 
checking whether the C compiler works... no
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'
/Users/tyler/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/tyler/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/tyler/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I have tried googling this problem but have had no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some more googling, I found this solution to my problem.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25561

Run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` then reboot your machine. CD into iOS directory of your product and run `pod install`. It should build correctly!

Comment: for the sake of god i tried this one like `sudo xcode-select --switch "/Applications/Xcode 13.4.1.app"` to point the xcode i use and the d*mn thing still didn't work. i then rename my xcode from `Xcode 13.4.1.app` to `Xcode.app` and do `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` then it all works!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I got this error when I'm on a macOS Catalina, that was installed on unsupported Apple computer (Mac mini 5.1 - mid-2011)

If you’ve stumbled upon this post, it most likely means that you’re getting this error:

> SDK “iphoneos” cannot be located

When trying to run a **`pod install`** or perform similar command-line tasks from a Mac terminal while working on an XCode project.

This is a typical scenario when you update a lot of stuff together – such as XCode and CocoaPods.

Luckily enough, the fix is very simple: open a new terminal window and type the following command:

```
sudo xcode-select --print-path
```

If XCode is installed, you should see a ***wrong*** installation path, such as `/Library/Developer/` or something like that: it’s very likely that your XCode installation is located somewhere else – such as in the `/Applications/` folder. If that’s so, you can fix your issue by typing the following command:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Make sure your Command Line Tools are selected in the XCode.
`XCode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools > Select the one that you want to use`

Step 2: Execute the following command in your terminal `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`

The trick here is that, if your XCode app is named differently such as `XCode 13.2.1`, even if you specify it like this `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode\ 13.2.1.app` it won't work and I think its because of the space in the name. Just rename you application itself to `XCode13.2.1`(basically remove any space in the name) and then execute `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode13.2.1.app`

Step 3: `pod install`