# React native ios - error when running pod install (installing Flipper-Glog)

Tags: react-native, podfile, flipper

When I try to run pod install, an error is generated at when program reaches `Installing Flipper-Glog (0.3.6)`
below is the error message in its entirety:

```
Installing Flipper-Glog (0.3.6)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h
/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif
/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif
/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot 
checking whether the C compiler works... no
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'
/Users/jamesmurphy/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/jamesmurphy/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/jamesmurphy/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Im using react native `0.63.3`
...and below is my podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'xs' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications/Permission-Notifications.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera/Permission-Camera.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways/Permission-LocationAlways.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse/Permission-LocationWhenInUse.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary/Permission-PhotoLibrary.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-MediaLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/MediaLibrary/Permission-MediaLibrary.podspec"

  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
  
  pod 'RNSound', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound'

  target 'xsTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

UPDATE 2/21
If you comment out the below code in Podfile....then the build gets further (as it doesnt install `Flipper-Glog`)...but it instead fails at `Installing glog (0.3.5)`

```
# use_flipper!()
# post_install do |installer|
#   react_native_post_install(installer)
# end
```

Looking into the stack-trace, it appears below are the errors:

```
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'
configure: error: in/Users/jamesmurphy/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-73c24:
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error trying to install react native, not building correctly when running pod install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556303/error-trying-to-install-react-native-not-building-correctly-when-running-pod-in)

Answer (score 24):

In my case, just selecting Command Line Tools on Xcode Settings and it will fix.

1. Click on Xcode from top left corner in Toolbar.
2. Click on Prefrence
3. Click on Location
4. Select Command Line Tools ( it should not be empty . In my case it was empty. Once i choose version then problem solve.)

[image]

Comment: Even if some Command Line Tools is selected, open select and confirm it again. It fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Running sudo xcode-select --reset works for me

Answer (score 1):

This error in my case was related with the Command Line Tools configuration. I just select my Xcode version as explain React Native on their documentation
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools

Answer (score 1):

I got this same issue but the problem was quite different (and simpler) for me, just sharing in case it'll help someone in the future.

I moved Xcode in an external SSD, and my RN project failed installing pods. Turns out the issue was that the name I gave my SSD contained spaces. So after renaming it from "Samsung SSD" to "SamsungSSD" all the pods were successfully installed.

Comment: This was exactly the issue on my side, thanks for sharing this solution

Answer (score 0):

After commenting out the flipper code as noted in my question update....the combination of the 2 answers below solved my issue:
[Xcode, Pods ProjectName.debug.xcconfig unable to open file. Wrong directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558984/xcode-pods-projectname-debug-xcconfig-unable-to-open-file-wrong-directory)
(answer by @pragmus)
[xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565356/xcrun-error-sdk-iphoneos-cannot-be-located) (answer by @Karrar Al-Mimar)

Answer (score 0):

Delete pod folder and pod.lock in iOS and run the "pod update"